# BibLaTex and citing same source several times in same paragraph

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I have encountered a strange problem in a thesis, where I try to cite a book several times in the same paragraph, referring to different pages in the book.
This results in the citations following the first is that only the page number is shown (as a simple number). Is there a (simple) way to force these citations to mimic the first?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4 paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
authordate,
backend=biber,
natbib,
maxbibnames=99,
]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@BOOK{orton,
  title = {Survey of English Dialects},
  publisher = {Leeds: Arnold},
  year = {1962},
  author = {Orton, Harold},
  volume = {IV},
  date-added = {2014-04-20 12:50:04 +0000},
  date-modified = {2014-04-24 18:41:22 +0000}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

This is a quote \citep[117]{orton} .  And then the second quote by the same person which results in the strange behaviour  \citep[224]{orton}.

In the next paragraph the third quote compiles just like the second \citep[332]{orton}, and then a different kind of quote by Orton compiles like a dream \citeyearpar[340]{orton}. But the last one has the same problem as number two and three \citep[345]{orton}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Look at section 5.4.1 in the documentation for `biblatex-chicago` for information on this feature, the section about "ibidtracker=constrict".

Comment: @pst Make that an answer, please? Adding a note that this is indeed intended behaviour.

Comment: I don't have time to formulate it. Up for grabs!

Comment: @pst I have added an answer, hope you're OK with that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually intended behaviour with `biblatex-chicago`; the [`biblatex-chicago` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-chicago/doc/biblatex-chicago.pdf) remarks (p. 112, §5.4.1 Pre-set `biblatex` Options):

> The Chicago author-date style doesn’t print “Ibid” in citations, but
>   in general a repeated citation on the same page will print only the
>   page reference. Technically, this should only occur when a source is
>   cited “more than once in one paragraph” (15.26), so you can use the
>   `\citereset` command from `biblatex` to achieve the greatest
>   compliance, as the package only offers automatic resetting on part,
>   chapter, section, and subsection boundaries, while `biblatex-chicago`
>   automatically resets the tracker at page breaks. (Cf. [biblatex.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)
>   §3.1.2.1.) Whenever there might be any ambiguity, `biblatex` should
>   default to printing a more informative reference. If you are going to
>   repeat a source, make sure that the cite command provides a postnote —
>   from this release of `biblatex-chicago` you’ll no longer get any
>   annoying empty  parentheses, but you will get another standard
>   citation, which may add too much clutter.

`biblatex-chicago` enables `ibidtracker=constrict` to track these citations.

If you insist on full citations every time, go with `ibidtracker=false`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  authordate,
  backend=biber,
  natbib,
  maxbibnames=99,
  ibidtracker=false,
]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
  This is a quote \citep[117]{wilde}. 
  And then the second quote by the same person which results in the strange behaviour \citep[224]{wilde}.

  In the next paragraph the third quote compiles just like the second \citep[332]{wilde},
  and then a different kind of quote by Orton compiles like a dream \citeyearpar[340]{wilde}.
  But the last one has the same problem as number two and three \citep[345]{wilde}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

The fact that "a different kind of quote by Orton compiles like a dream" is due to your using `\citeyearpar` that is not affected by the ibid checks.

Comment: Big thanks both to @pst and moewe for very good answers!